# Selecting all rows from one table grouped by unique values from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have simple database with two tables.

In `teams` table there are columns `team` and `id`.
`players` table has columns `player_name`, `player_age`, `position` and `team_id`.

`team_id` in `players` table is foreign key that refers to `team_name` in `teams` table.

I want to display this information in HTML table using PHP where I will have header with `team_name`, `player_name` and `player_age`.

I need only unique `team_name` values because I want to echo whole table using while loop so I need them to only echo once in header. I hope this makes sense.

My problem is, I don't know how to write a query which will return distinct `team_name` values from `teams` table but all players and age info from `players` table.

I've tried using joins but I always end up having same number of `team_name` values as `player_name` values.

I do this for exercise only so any security issues and stuff like that are not my concern right now.

Comment: Please show us some sample data here which explains your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I explained my tables, they're pretty simple. I am willing to further explain if needed but I'm missing what's not clear.

I have tables that are fully explained up there and php file where I'll fetch query. Then I'll use while loop which will go something like 
    

`while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_of_query)){
    //table structure here 
}`

Answer (score 1):

assuming you want show the relation for the team with id = 3  you can use  a join as

```
select t.team_name, p.player_name, p.player_age
from teams t 
inner join players p on p.team_id = t.id
and t.id = 3
```

or if you want the relation based on team name

```
select t.team_name, p.player_name, p.player_age
from teams t 
inner join players p on p.team_id = t.id
and t.team_name = 'your_preferred_team_name'
```

if you want all team in a single query then

```
select t.team_name, p.player_name, p.player_age
from teams t 
inner join players p on p.team_id = t.id
Order by t.id
```

Comment: Using this method I would have to write separate queries for all the teams and when new team is added I would have to write another query.

Comment: @trbste Remove the "and" statement and loop through the result. :)

Comment: @trbste   answer  update for a single query for all the team  ..but if you want show one team separated .. you must think at an  outer loop based  on a query for all the team that for each team id select the related players  (as suggested  by Joshua McNab)